# How would I stop a program if two get opts are called

Tags: c++

> If both ­r and ­c are specified, the behavior can change depending on which is executed first. Don't allow a user to specify both. Give them an error message and exit if they try

How would I do this using getopt function?

How can I stop a user from passing both options at the same time?

Comment: If getopt doesn't support mutual exclusion then you could just add a check after the getopt call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getopt()` simply gives you access to the parsed command-line options. It is up to you to actually validate them.  As you are looping through the options, keep track of whether you have encountered the `r` and `c` options.  If you encounter the `r` option and have already `encountered` the `c` option, or vice versa, then exit.